# Gcloud kubernetes/docker deploy works but stops responding after 10 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

So I've taken on a deployment onto the google container engine and have run into a weird behaviour I don't really know how to debug. I am deploying a ruby on rails application using docker and kubernetes.

I am basically following this tutorial: 
https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-node#step_2_create_a_docker_container_image skipping the spinning up replicas section and it works. I can go to the external IP after building/deploying and my app functions the way it is intended. However, after 10 minutes or so it stops. Requests just spin forever.

I have found the log files to be relatively unhelpful seeing only the following that would strike hint:

```
{
"log": "2015/11/10 05:35:18 Worker running nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost >/dev/null\n",
"stream": "stderr"
}

{
"log": "2015/11/10 05:35:19 Client ip xx.xxx.x.x:xxxxx requesting    /healthz probe servicing cmd nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local     localhost >/dev/null\n",
"stream": "stderr"
}
```

I have been through most of the debugging suggestions on this page: 
https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/debugging/

kubectl logs ${pod}:

```
[2015-11-10 05:07:44] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-11-10 05:07:44] INFO  ruby 2.1.6 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-11-10 05:07:44] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=80
```

kubectl logs $pod $instance unnervingly returns:

```
Container "x" not found in Pod "x"
```

Dockerfile is pretty much straight from google:

```
FROM google/ruby

# [START postgres-dep]
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -qy --no-install-recommends libpq-dev && \
apt-get clean
# [END postgres-dep]

ENV RACK_ENV production

WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN /usr/bin/bundle install --deployment --without development:test
ADD . /app
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile
RUN bundle exec rake db:migrate
EXPOSE 8080
ENV RACK_ENV production
CMD ["/usr/bin/bundle", "exec", "rackup", "-p", "80", "/app/config.ru", "-s", "webrick", "-E", "production"]
```

pinging returns the following:

```
PING xxxxx (xxxxx): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from xxxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=49 time=48.462 ms
64 bytes from xxxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=48.177 ms
64 bytes from 1xxxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=48.181 ms
64 bytes from xxxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=48.240 ms
64 bytes from 1xxxxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=48.337 ms
64 bytes from xxxxx: icmp_seq=5 ttl=49 time=48.149 ms 
64 bytes from xxxxx: icmp_seq=6 ttl=49 time=48.053 ms
64 bytes from xxxx: icmp_seq=7 ttl=49 time=47.958 ms
64 bytes from xxxxx: icmp_seq=8 ttl=49 time=48.137 ms
```

the latency looks pretty bad. After forever it does point to the red rails screen of death'

Questions:
  Where are my darn application logs? I don't see anything rails like in the developers console and couldn't find them via ssh either. I sort of assumed it was a balancer/pod config issue but it would be nice to know anyway.
  Why does it work initially and after a while stop functioning? Where do I begin to troubleshoot behaviour like this when everything says it has the green light with no critical logs?
  Are rolling updates(https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/rolling-updates) the process for re-deploying code changes without spinning up and down/re creating everything?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where are my darn application logs?

`kubectl logs` will grab any logs that are written to stdout / stderr. If your application logs to a file, then you'll need to look at that file directly to see your logs. Try `kubectl exec` to get a shell inside your pod and then use your favorite tool (cat, grep, less, etc) to view the log file (check out [this blog post](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2015/10/some-things-you-didnt-know-about-kubectl_28.html) if you haven't already to see some neat uses of kubectl, including an example of `kubectl exec`).

> Why does it work initially and after a while stop functioning?

This probably depends on your application. Once you get the logs, you should be able to tell.

> Are [rolling updates](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/rolling-updates) the process for re-deploying code changes without spinning up and down/re creating everything?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks Robert I thought it was weird the only logs returned from kubectl logs was server startup message. Haven't had much sleep in the last week and didn't put 2 and 2 together. It ended up being an issue regarding their demo walkthrough suggesting lunchy 2.4 which wasn't playing nice with postgres.

Comment: Can you give the link to kubectl exec blog post here it didn't seem to get through formatting?

Comment: http://blog.kubernetes.io/2015/10/some-things-you-didnt-know-about-kubectl_28.html